# Visual Studio 2010 - configuring SSL for website inside web setup project

Tags: asp.net, ssl, web-setup-project

I have a web application (http handler) which uses SSL. I now want to create a web setup for this web application and I wonder if there is a possibility to tell the setup project that the application should use SSL. I want to do this because this handler will be used in clients machines and I just want to application to runs correctly under HTTPS after it is installed (user should not need to go to IIS and configure SSL for that website). I searched for a specific property under File System in the setup project but there is no such option. Maybe I can do this using some custom actions? Application uses certificate issued by a Trusted Root Certification Authority and it is already installed.